# How to remove data which doesn't begin with 'xa' in my code?

Tags: r

I have some data which looks like:
[image]

I want to remove rows 4 and 5 because they don't contain data preceding "xa".

My code is:

```
is.na(x$column)
```

But it returns with TRUE for row 4 but false for row 5. This is just an example but I have many other random pieces of data in the column, but I just want a way to select for when the data is "xaN", with n representing any integer.

Comment: `subset(df, grepl('^xa', column))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From base R:

`grepl()` searches for character "xa" at the beginning of the string (by regex `^`) and returns a logical value, which can be used by `subset`.

```
subset(df, grepl("^xa", column))

  Row column
1   1  xa123
2   2  xa456
3   3 xa5555
```

#### Data

```
structure(list(Row = 1:5, column = c("xa123", "xa456", "xa5555", 
".", "-")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 3):

We can determine the rows that start with `xa`, then keep only those rows.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(column, "^xa"))
```

Or in base R:

```
df[grepl("^xa", df$column),]
```

**Output**

```
  Row column
1   1  xa123
2   2  xa456
3   3 xa5555
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Row = 1:5, column = c("xa123", "xa456", "xa5555", 
".", "-")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 3):

A `data.table` approach using  `%like%` operator with partial match:

```
library("data.table")  
df[df$column %like% "^xa", ]
```

```
    Row column
  <dbl> <chr> 
1     1 xa1   
2     2 xa456 
3     3 xa555
```

Comment: Changed my answer to a new one!

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(Row = 1:5,
                 column = c("xa123", "xa456", "xa5555", NA, "-"))

df[!is.na(df$column) & substr(df$column, 1, 2) == "xa", ]
```

Result:

```
  Row column
1   1  xa123
2   2  xa456
3   3 xa5555
```